# How do I instantiate a variadic tuple of unknown size with known non-default constructors?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a `std::tuple` of types. I don't know how many or what types it contains, but I know that each element has a constructor taking a single argument.

For the sake of this question, let's say that argument is the integer `5`, **but the value is not known until runtime**.

How can I construct such a tuple?

Here is my attempt so far, which attempts to construct the tuple with a compile-time constant (*not* what I want, but it's a starting point):

```
#include <tuple>                                                                 

struct Fixture                                                                   
{

    // I don't know the value until runtime, so this is a poor
    // example anyway.
    template <typename T>                                                        
    struct Unpack                                                                
    {                                                                            
        static const int value = 5;                                    
    };                                                                           

    template <typename... T>                                                     
    struct Y                                                                     
    {                                                                            
        Y()                                                                      
        :   
            // this needs to be a runtime value                                                                     
            tup(Unpack<T>::value...)                                             
        {                                                                        
        }                                                                        

        std::tuple<T...> tup;                                                    
    };                                                                           

    Y<int, double, unsigned /*, some other classes */> y;                                                          
};
```

Other than being ugly (that `Unpack` class shouldn't be necessary) and only working with a constant value known at compile time, this also results in a linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "Fixture::Unpack::value", referenced from:
>         Fixture::Y::Y() in testTest.cpp.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there some metaprogramming magic in the Standard Library or Boost that can make this work, preferably with more concise syntax? I feel like something along the lines of `std::integer_sequence` might help me, but I can't figure out how!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz really? What's the type?

Comment: At least some compiler are fine with that. [live](http://ideone.com/dfUHAJ) -- also tested with `Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)`. What are you using?

Comment: @Hiura same version as you. Anyway this is not a great example because in the actual code I only know the value at runtime. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: Why not just make `Y`'s constructor take `T...`'s as parameters ?

Comment: why not using `std::make_tuple`? it does exactly that...

Comment: @Quentin because I want to construct all of them with a single number, not with `T...`'s

Comment: @DavidHaim could you explain?

Comment: read about `std::make_tuple`.

Comment: if you know the value only at runtime, you cannot use const/constexpr. Does [this example](http://ideone.com/7TJRPh) reflects your intention?

Comment: @Hiura yes this is getting close! The problem is we don't know the types in the tuple, so we can't manually instantiate each of the types to define the static members.

Comment: @m.s. I think you're right. Feel free to mark as duplicate. Thanks for finding this :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to construct an expression which references the variadic pack, but whose value is your parameter. Upon expansion, it will become a repetition of your parameter. The comma operator does that very well :

```
template <typename... T>
struct Y
{
    Y(int value)
    : tup((void(sizeof(T)), value)...)
    { }

    std::tuple<T...> tup;
};
```

The cast to `void` is to explicitly discard the value of the left side of the comma. `sizeof(T)` can be replaced with anything referencing `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the const on your value, you can use this

```
template<typename T>
T Fixture::Unpack<T>::value{};
```

to define every possible "unpack type".

Then you can use at runtime something like that to update the value:

```
int main() {
    std::cin >> Fixture::Unpack<int>::value >> Fixture::Unpack<double>::value;
    Fixture f;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(f.y.tup) << " " << std::get<1>(f.y.tup);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/kRgYEL)